# Light having higher momentum in glass than in vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light

We know that light has momentum. Under normal conditions, momentum is given by E/c where E is the energy of the EMW and c is the speed of light in a vacuum.

If say light enters glass, with a certain refractive index, c would go down to v.

As far as I know, frequency doesn't change, nor does the energy of the wave. So is the momentum transfer now gonna be more? (since now its E/v)

Even looking at this as the photonic picture, wavelength = h/p so reducing wavelength would increase the momentum of the photon.

Is this correct? How would one physically explain such an increase in the momentum transfer? If anything, one would expect it to go down!

Comment: You should probably check this:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44509/photon-energy-momentum-in-matter

Comment: ahhh yes! thank you!